# Using mapply where the arguments are specified by a data frame

Tags: r, apply, mapply

I am trying to use a function lots of times and vary the arguments each time. The arguments I want to vary also change.

I am trying to use a data frame where the column names specify which arguments I want to change.

For example, imagine we are using `mapply` to multiple 1:3 by 4 and 5:

```
f <- function(A, B, C = 1) A * B * C
mapply(f, A = rep(1:3, 2), B = rep(4:5, each = 3))
```

We can use `expand.grid` to make things easier:

```
arg <- expand.grid(A = 1:3, B = 4:5)
mapply(f, A = arg$A, B = arg$B)
```

I am trying to do this:

```
mapply(f, arg)
```

Such that the arguments `A` and `B` are specified in the input `arg`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `do.call`

```
do.call(Map, c(f = f, arg))
```

Or with `mapply`

```
do.call(mapply, c(FUN = f, arg))
#[1]  4  8 12  5 10 15
```